# Can send Ajax request from a Shiny Application

Tags: ajax, shiny, shiny-server

Can send Ajax request from a Shiny Application, hosted in Shiny server?

Comment: https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/tree/master/api-ajax

Comment: Thanks @Pork, This Ajax-like implements Shiny solution : https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-send-message.html. my aim is to send ajax to another server from Js in Shiny.